# How can I make celery more robust with regards to dropped tasks?

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery

Occasionally (read: too often) my celery setup will drop tasks. I'm running the latest `celery 4.x` on `Django 1.11` with a `redis` backend for the queue and results.

I don't know exactly why tasks are being dropped, but what I suspect is that a worker is starting a job, then the worker is killed for some reason (autoscaling action, redeployment, out-of-memory...) and the job is killed in the middle.

At this point probably it has exited the `redis` queue and it won't be picked up again.

So my questions are:

1. How can I monitor this kind of thing? I use `celerymon`, and the task is not reported as failed, and yet I don't see in my database the data that I expected by the task that I suspect failed.
2. How can I make `celery` retry such tasks without implementing my own "fake queue" with flags in the database?
3. How do I make `celery` more robust and dependable in general?

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use RabbitMq instead redis, I read this in the celery documentation(right here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#choosing-a-broker):

> RabbitMQ is feature-complete, stable, durable and easy to install. It’s an
> excellent choice for a production environment.
>
> Redis is also feature-complete, but is more susceptible to data loss in the
> event of abrupt termination or power failures.
>
> Using rabbit mq your problem of lossing message on restart have to gone.

Comment: Thanks! Is your answer still valid if I clarify that my Redis is not restarting (I use Elasticache on AWS), but it's the worker that is restarting?

Comment: Yes, the common problem is that, the workers die and loose the task that they are processing.

Comment: I did some googling and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577723/if-celery-worker-dies-hard-does-job-get-retried Does it ring a bell / do you have any experience with it? Thanks!

Comment: I have more experience with rabbit, that config `task_acks_late` worked?